# Where I can find .jar files of libraries?

Tags: android, maven, gradle, jar, dependencies

I need to download `com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:18.0.1` where I can find .jar file of that?

Answer (score -1):

You can usually find artifacts on Google Maven repository:
https://maven.google.com/web/index.html

Here's your example:
https://maven.google.com/web/index.html?q=play-services-ads-identifier#com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:18.0.1